# How I can in toolbar dynamically update symbols?

Tags: ios, swift, textview

I've textview and toolbar, which I added with code:

```
let toolBarController = UIToolbar()
toolBarController.sizeToFit()
postTextView.inputAccessoryView = toolBarController
```

I want put label in this toolbar and dynamically show symbols of textview. How this can be done?

I try to use button, but don't know how dynamically change its text:

```
let resultsLabel = UIBarButtonItem(title: "\(count)", style: .plain, target: self, action: nil)
resultsLabel.isEnabled = false
```

Comment: Maybe you need to set item? `toolBarController.setItems([resultsLabel], animated: true)` ?

Comment: Yes. But how I can change it value dynamycally to show symbols in texview?

Comment: I think you need a more complex implementation for that adjusting item with delegate from TextView component is a possible approach

Comment: Can you provide code sample, please?